# Highlighting Links in a Textbox

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am fetching Twitter updates, and displaying them on a Panoramic page. On one individual panoramic control, I have a list box containing textboxes, which displays all of the Twitter status.

I would like to highlight a link if it is in a Twitter status.

How can I highlight an individual piece of text in a Textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create your own control which parses the tweet and converts it into something that you can display.

In a similar scenario I parsed the text and added each word that wasn't a link to a `WrapPanel` as a `TextBlock` and the ones that were as `HyperlinkButton`s.

**Edit:**
Note: the WrapPanel is part of the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291).

Comment: How did you use a WrapPanel? I can't seem to find that control.

Comment: @Woody the WrapPanel is in the Silverlight Toolkit

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it out myself but [version 7.1 of the developer tools](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=77586864-ab15-40e1-bc38-713a95a56a05&displaylang=en) contains the [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=VS.96%29.aspx) class that allows all sorts of formatted text display options, including hyperlinks.

Of course, any app that uses this will have to wait until fall when MS releases the Mango update before it can be distributed to users.